# How To Combine Same Data to Horizontal Table

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I tried and read many posts but I still can't figure out how to handle this request:

I have a table like this:

```
+------+------+------+
|Device|PERIOD| DATE |
+------+------+------+
|A     |1     |1/1/11|
+------+------+------+
|A     |2     |2/1/11|
+------+------+------+
|B     |1     |3/1/11|
+------+------+------+
|B     |2     |4/1/11|
+------+------+------+
```

i would like to see output like this :

```
+------+--------+--------+
|Device|PERIOD 1|PERIOD 2|
+------+--------+--------+
|A     |1/1/11  |2/1/11  |
+------+--------+--------+
|B     |3/11/11 |4/1/11  |
+------+--------+--------+
```

Help Me guys, Thankyou :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use pivoting logic here:

```
SELECT
    Device,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PERIOD = 1 THEN DATE END) AS PERIOD1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PERIOD = 2 THEN DATE END) AS PERIOD2
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Device
ORDER BY
    Device;
```

Comment: ih tried this but why it show the same date for same period?

Comment: @AppHery You should edit your question with the actual data you are using.  My answer should be working for the data which you did show us.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for dynamic columns, we need go generate those string columns first using `group_concat()` function. Then add the generated column string your original query.

**Generated sql string:**

```
select Device, max(case when PERIOD = '1' then DATE end) AS `PERIOD 1`,max(case when PERIOD = '2' then DATE end) AS `PERIOD 2` 
        from test 
        group by Device
```

**Complete script:**

```
set @strsql = '';
select
  group_concat(distinct
    concat(
      'max(case when PERIOD = ''',
      PERIOD,
      ''' then DATE end) AS `PERIOD ',
      PERIOD, '`'
    )
  ) into @strsql
from test;

set @strsql = concat('select Device, ', @strsql, ' 
        from test 
        group by Device');

select @strsql;

prepare stmt from @strsql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e5c6ff6fc2501b8afb027ae34d475d2b).